# curl and wget not working with https sites after upgrade to ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: curl, https, openssl, wget, ubuntu-18.04

Seems to be a openssl related issue. Anyone have any ideas as to what this is?

Note that the url works in a browser.

With wget:

```
# wget -d https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x

DEBUG output created by Wget 1.19.4 on linux-gnu.

Reading HSTS entries from /home/user/.wget-hsts
URI encoding = ‘UTF-8’
Converted file name 'setup_8.x' (UTF-8) -> 'setup_8.x' (UTF-8)
--2018-09-02 19:54:06--  https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x
Could not seed PRNG; consider using --random-file.
OpenSSL: error:2406F07A:random number generator:RAND_load_file:Not a regular file
Disabling SSL due to encountered errors.
```

With curl:

```
# curl -v -L https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x

*   Trying 205.251.207.2...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to deb.nodesource.com (205.251.207.2) port 443 (#0)

<hangs>
```

Comment: This works fine in this vagrant box [benno/ubntu-18.04](https://app.vagrantup.com/bento/boxes/ubuntu-18.04) which is 18.04.1 as well. What is the exact version of the OpenSSL libraries these commands are using in your environment?

Comment: libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.1

Comment: What is the version showed when doing `strings /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.1 | grep ^OpenSSL`?

Comment: OpenSSL 1.1.1-dev  xx XXX xxxx

Comment: BTW one thing I realized is that wget linked with gnutls (instead of openssl) works fine. But the standard package that comes from the bionic archives is linked with openssl, and that fails in my environment.

Comment: Forget about my answer for a moment, could you check out this link [Could not seed PRNG; consider using --random-file.](https://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=227) and try the recommendation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be running into this OpenSSL bug/feature: [1.1.1 -> RAND_load_file() does not accept special files](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/5511).

Checking out the source code op `wget`, you can see that it invokes `RAND_load_file()` in the function [init_prng()](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/wget.git/tree/src/openssl.c#n65). That function also explains some options you could use to point to a different file (which should be a regular file):

```
  /* Seed from a file specified by the user.  This will be the file
     specified with --random-file, $RANDFILE, if set, or ~/.rnd, if it
     exists.  */
```

You could try any of these, or otherwise use a `1.1.0`-version of OpenSSL. Or use `gnutls`, like you already do :-)

---

By the way, I was not able to reproduce your problem, so I can not tell for sure this is the cause. However, I do not think that your problem is caused by the upgrade to 18.04.1. Your current OpenSSL installation seems a bit messed up by something else. The version number indicates that this a build from an untagged OpenSSL repository state. I would not expect those libraries to be in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before the "standard" OpenSSL libraries which reside in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.

---

Based on the comments back and forth, the final conclusion is that you have built and installed a version of OpenSSL `1.1.1` in the past and at that time it worked fine. But after updating to `18.04.1`, the bug mentioned was exposed. It would be interesting to figure out which exact changes in that update caused it, but I suppose knowing the immediate answer to your question is good enough for now :-)

Comment: Yes, I saw that issue on the openssl github as well. The suggestion on there didn't seem to help though. And in any case, I'd really like to understand why this is broken for us here (there are other people with the same problem). Also, I am not sure what you mean by "build from a untagged repo". The openssl package is what came with Ubuntu (I am pretty sure). What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: I do not think this particular openssl package came with Ubuntu. The version number `OpenSSL 1.1.1-dev xx XXX xxxx` is not something you would see in a normal distro and the location of where you get your OpenSSL libraries from does not seem to be the standard location. Do you see OpenSSL libraries in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` as well?

Comment: All I have there is: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openssl-1.0.0/engines.

Comment: I do not know much about Ubuntu packaging but my clean 18.04.1 install looks different. Maybe you should manually instal the openssl package(s). This confirmed but unassigned bug report might be another indication that your OpenSSL 1.1.1 version is not part of the official distro: [Please provide ED25519 support in 18.04 OpenSSL](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/1780807)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Saw a post from openssl folks saying something similar, and couldn't make sense of it.

Comment: That was the problem - openssl-1.1.1. Seems like, at some point, we built and installed it, and most of us have it on our machines. And upgrade to bionic was exposing the "bug" in there. If you reflect this in your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: OK, I added a conclusion -- feel free to edit to your liking. This was probably the last time that you installed an un-official version of OpenSSL, no?